# Delphi to java, soap delphi, sms send

Tags: java, delphi, sms, send, soap-client

I am working on a code which I need to send sms messages from a sms service provider they get me delphy program that can send a sms from their service but i dont know delphy and i should change this code to java
Can anyboddy guide me that how can i change this code?
I think this is a soap service

```
    // ************************************************************************ //

// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the

// WSDL File described below:

// WSDL     : http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/?wsdl

// Encoding : ISO-8859-1

// Version  : 1.0

// (8/14/2007 6:51:27 PM - 1.33.2.5)

// ************************************************************************ //



unit IMihanSMSCenterService;



interface



uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;



type



  // ************************************************************************ //

  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented

  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred

  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category

  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Borland types; however, they could also 

  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.

  // ************************************************************************ //

  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  // !:int             - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"



  stringArray = array of WideString;            { "http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/" }

  intArray   = array of Integer;                { "http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/" }



  // ************************************************************************ //

  // Namespace : http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/

  // soapAction: http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/#%operationName%

  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http

  // style     : rpc

  // binding   : mihansmscenterWSDLBinding

  // service   : mihansmscenterWSDL

  // port      : mihansmscenterWSDLPort

  // URL       : http://www.mihansmscenter.com/webservice/index.php

  // ************************************************************************ //

  mihansmscenterWSDLPortType = interface(IInvokable)

  ['{7B1648E6-5147-A087-2C5C-7FF87155D985}']

    procedure send(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const to_: WideString; const from: WideString; const message: WideString; const send_time: Integer; out status: Integer; out identifier: Integer; out status_message: WideString); stdcall;

    procedure multiSend(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const to_: stringArray; const from: WideString; const message: WideString; const send_time: Integer; out status: Integer; out send_results: intArray; out identifiers: intArray; out status_message: WideString

                        ); stdcall;

    procedure checkSendStatus(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const identifier: Integer; out status: Integer; out sendStatus: Integer; out status_message: WideString); stdcall;

    procedure bulkSend(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const count: Integer; const from: WideString; const message: WideString; const description: WideString; out status: Integer; out status_message: WideString); stdcall;

    procedure verifyReceive(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const to_: WideString; const from: WideString; const message: WideString; const timestamp: Integer; out status: Integer; out status_message: WideString); stdcall;

    procedure accountInfo(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; out status: Integer; out status_message: WideString; out remaining_sms: Integer; out total_sms: Integer; out received_sms: Integer; out sent_sms: Integer; out recieve_url: WideString; out sms_numbers: stringArray

                          ); stdcall;

    procedure changeReceiveURL(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const receive_url: WideString; out status: Integer; out status_message: WideString); stdcall;

    procedure changePassword(const username: WideString; const password: WideString; const new_password: WideString; out status: Integer; out status_message: WideString); stdcall;

  end;



function GetmihansmscenterWSDLPortType(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): mihansmscenterWSDLPortType;





implementation



function GetmihansmscenterWSDLPortType(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): mihansmscenterWSDLPortType;

const

  defWSDL = 'http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/?wsdl';

  defURL  = 'http://www.mihansmscenter.com/webservice/index.php';

  defSvc  = 'mihansmscenterWSDL';

  defPrt  = 'mihansmscenterWSDLPort';

var

  RIO: THTTPRIO;

begin

  Result := nil;

  if (Addr = '') then

  begin

    if UseWSDL then

      Addr := defWSDL

    else

      Addr := defURL;

  end;

  if HTTPRIO = nil then

    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)

  else

    RIO := HTTPRIO;

  try

    Result := (RIO as mihansmscenterWSDLPortType);

    if UseWSDL then

    begin

      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;

      RIO.Service := defSvc;

      RIO.Port := defPrt;

    end else

      RIO.URL := Addr;

  finally

    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then

      RIO.Free;

  end;

end;





initialization

  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(mihansmscenterWSDLPortType), 'http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/', 'ISO-8859-1');

  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(mihansmscenterWSDLPortType), 'http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/#%operationName%');

  InvRegistry.RegisterExternalParamName(TypeInfo(mihansmscenterWSDLPortType), 'send', 'to_', 'to');

  InvRegistry.RegisterExternalParamName(TypeInfo(mihansmscenterWSDLPortType), 'multiSend', 'to_', 'to');

  InvRegistry.RegisterExternalParamName(TypeInfo(mihansmscenterWSDLPortType), 'verifyReceive', 'to_', 'to');

  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(stringArray), 'http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/', 'stringArray');

  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(intArray), 'http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/', 'intArray');



end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only bit you are interested in is the WSDL:

```
http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/?wsdl
```

Pick one of the Java WS APIs - Axis, JAX-WS, etc - then generate the client stubs for the web-service from the WSDL and write your Java code to work against those.

The rest of the Delphi code is pretty much useless to you.  You might want to ask for the code that uses the Delphi interface, just so you can see how the calls are being made - stuff like are the passwords encrypted, etc because you'll obviously want to conform to that.